# C#, .Net 4.5 - где в нём библиотека с векторами?

Tags: c#, vector, .net-4.5

Нашёл в System.Numerics тип Vector3, но почему-то его в моей системе нет. В каком он пространстве имён? Или 3d-вектор нужно самому писать? Я такого не видел с 2010 года. Я пишу на чистом C#, не на Unity, и не могу найти ответ в куче ненужной информации..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[System.Numerics](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Numerics.Vectors) поставляется в nuget-пакете и доступен и для 4.5. Но богатством типов он не блещет - попробуйте посмотреть еще на [Math.NET Numerics](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MathNet.Numerics/) в разделе [матриц](http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/Matrix.html), там все куда развесистее.

Comment: System.Numerics.Vectors использует SIMD на аппаратном уровне, что очень ускоряет вычисления.

Comment: Помниться мне, Math.NET снизу тоже использует нативные библиотеки (типа интеловских), но могу и ошибаться.

Comment: Посмотрел стек технологий, которые могут использоваться, был сильно удивлён. Коммерческий пакет с матрицами FinMath Numerical Library использует библиотеки от Интел(тоже не бесплатные), а библиотеки эти попадают под санкции. В том числе использование в таких странах, как Иран, Сирия и в Крыму. То есть при коммерческом использовании их могут не продать, а если продадут, то "не разрешается использование для разработки оружия(биологического, химического, ядерного)" и ещё там есть проверки по серийным номерам - короче, они используют возможности своего железа, а код этот - обвешан жучками...

Comment: Хотя мне всё равно.

Answer (score 4):

Тип Vector3 появился в .NET 4.6 Соответственно, в .NET 4.5 его нет